# England need or needs?

Tags: verb-agreement

During cricket matches I always hear commentators to say **England need 8 runs to win.**
Is it grammatical?

Comment: Yes. This is not about the country, but about the team.

Comment: England have/has 11 players? ?

Comment: BrE uses a plural for national football teams.

Comment: It uses plural for many collective nouns (i.e. where something consists of multiple people). "The police" springs to mind, but of course there are many more examples.

Comment: I doubt that you've heard Aussie commentators using synesis there.